# Would below scenario cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Would below scenario cause a memory leak?

**Case 1**

Here, I am not using new operator and so I am not sure how it works in Java when we do not user new operator and do assignment of object1 to object2.

```
public void doSomething() {
     String a1 = "Hello";
     String a2;

     while(true) {
         a2 = a1;
     }
 }
```

**Case 2**

Here,

```
public void doSomething() {
     String a1 = new String("Hello");
     String a2;

     while(true) {
         a2 = new String(a1);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Neither would cause a memory leak. The second example *might* keep the garbage collector busy.

Comment: 1) No, assigning a reference to another variable doesn't allocate more space. 2) No, the new string created in each iteration of the loop can be garbage collected as soon as the reference is overridden on the next iteration. It will trigger many GC runs, to free up the space, but it's not leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

## Case 1

You're not allocating any more memory, so you can't be leaking any. After one loop, variables `a1` and `a2` will reference the exact same single `String` instance.

## Case 2

No, as it stands all the `String` instances you are creating will just be garbage collected, but you're not far off:

```
while(true) {
    a2 = new String(a1);
    a2.intern();
}
```

By placing the string in the PermGen (Permanent Generation) of the garbage collector, and then losing any references to it (in the next loop iteration) this would classify as a memory leak.